# Netty: Stalls during disconnects / reconnects

Tags: java, tcp, netty

I am experiencing some strange behaviour with Netty (3.6.6):

I have built a simple client-server architecture whereby the client connects to the server over TCP via Netty.  The client includes logic to re-establish the connection if it becomes disconnected, backing off and retrying indefinitely.

The problem: If I forcibly disconnect the client a number of times it reaches a point where reconnection attempts begin to fail.  They continue to fail for a number of connection attempts, lasting a few minutes and then resume working (!).

Some other points:

- The number of disconnects required to cause a failure corresponds to the number of threads in the worker pool; e.g. for a single threaded worker pool I only have to disconnect the client once for the problem to occur.  For a thread pool containing 8 threads I need to perform 8 disconnects for the problem to occur.
- Once in a "failure state" the recovery period is shorter the more threads I have in the worker pool.  Also, when in a failure state all worker threads appear to be blocked on the internal selector.
- When debugging I notice that in a failed `connect()` attempt the `Channel` is open but not connected.

Has anyone experienced this problem?

**Initialisation Code** (executed once)

```
    Executor bossPool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(new SimpleThreadFactory("I/O Boss Thread"));
    Executor workerPool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    ChannelFactory channelFactory = new NioClientSocketChannelFactory(bossPool, workerPool);

    bootstrap = new ClientBootstrap(channelFactory);
```

**Connection Code** (executed upon reconnect attempt)

```
    // SimpleChannelHandler responsible for establishing which protocol we're speaking.
    SalutationHandler salutationHandler = new SalutationHandler(messageCodec);

    // Reconfigure pipeline to initial state.
    // Will be reconfigured again after initial client-server handshaking.
    bootstrap.setPipeline(configureNewPipeline(Channels.pipeline(salutationHandler)));

    // Wait for up to 5 seconds before timing out.
    wrapChannelFuture(bootstrap.connect(address)).sync(timeOutMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: what do you mean by "forcibly disconnect"? and what error do you see when a reconnection attempt fails?